# Get sum of cells containing "Vacation" except when related date matches certain day & month

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, lookup-tables

oversimplified i have two columns: Date and Text; I want to check my current amount of vacation days based on the first date in row 2, so i came up with the following formula:

`="Available vacation days: "&YEARFRAC(A2;TODAY())*12*(25/12)`

I calculate the fraction of the year based on the first date and todays date, multiply it by 12 to get months and multiply it again by the total amount of vacation days in my contract per month. Now i got another formula to collect me all cells in column B containing "Vacation", pretty straight forward:

`=COUNTIF(B:B;"Vacation")`

Now the interesting part - i got the formula who gives me a boolean if a datetime matches the 24th or 31st of december:

`=AND(OR(DAY(A53)=24;DAY(A53)=31);MONTH(A53)=12)`

I want to count vacation days happening on a 24th or 31st of december as a half-vacation day (0.5), and otherwise fully (as a 1). Then i want to combine my first statement with this result and subtract the used vacation days. I read about VLOOKUP and XLOOKUP but am unsure if this fits this purpose. I want to avoid having an extra column with my boolean returns and rather have this one cell giving me all the information combined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without introducing another column, and using `DAY` and `MONTH`
It's nearly impossible, and just unnecessarily so...
***Please*** reconsider this, what will happen if you want to add 4th of July as a holiday?

Your formula `=AND(OR(DAY(A53)=24;DAY(A53)=31);MONTH(A53)=12)` only works for 1 row at a time. So, we can't ever use it with a list, because you will get the whole list as a result every single time. You can't divide them into smaller lists and join them together, there is no such functionality without VBA.

In the future, do not set arbitrary constraints like "no additional columns", you can hide them if you don't like them. And if you don't need them, remove unnecessary rows like non-vacation rows. They are irrelevant, so why not separate the two.

Just to prove my point, here's the solution you wanted:

## Solution

```
=COUNTIFS(B2:B9;"Vacation") - (COUNT(IFERROR(FILTER(FILTER(FILTER(A2:A9;B2:B9="Vacation");MONTH(FILTER(A2:A9;B2:B9="Vacation"))=12);DAY(FILTER(FILTER(A2:A9;B2:B9="Vacation");MONTH(FILTER(A2:A9;B2:B9="Vacation"))=12))=31);0))+(COUNT(IFERROR(FILTER(FILTER(FILTER(A2:A9;B2:B9="Vacation");MONTH(FILTER(A2:A9;B2:B9="Vacation"))=12);DAY(FILTER(FILTER(A2:A9;B2:B9="Vacation");MONTH(FILTER(A2:A9;B2:B9="Vacation"))=12))=24);0))))*0,5
```

It works, but it's a pain to read, use and maintain.

`A2:A9` refers to the dates column
`B2:B9` refers to the text column

So in the future, the last thing you want to do is set arbitrary constraints. Furthermore, why use functions like `MONTH` and `DAY` when we can just read the text? That way you could even create a table of holidays to search for instead. That will be no fun task with this setup. (Oh, and if it's because of the year, just strip it away from the text when you want to know only the month and day.

Best of luck!

Comment: You are right, this is a pain to read and use. Also you are right, that i shouldnt constrain myself by not wanting an additional column when i can hide it, to be honest i didnt think of that and it might be much easier. However, you answered my question and explained it throughly, so thank you for that :) Have a nice christmas!